# What is the use of .blade in the Laravel framework?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I encountered the file `welcome.blade.php` in the `views` folder.

What is the purpose of `.blade` in the file's name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel uses `Blade Template` as its template engine (e.g. `smarty` was quite popular in past ) and `.blade.php` is extension used for it. Can find more details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#introduction)

Comment: If I don't put the .blade in a file name what will happen?

Comment: Try it and see what happens

Comment: Long story short, your views will stop working.. As @AndyHolmes mentioned try it, read and understand the link I shared.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Abbasi Blade is a templating engine. I just wanted to share a good resource for blade and Laravel in general which provides some nice examples like:

```
@extends('layout.name')
// Begin a section
 @section('name')
// End a section
 @stop
// End a section and yield
 @show
@parent
// Show a section in a template
 @yield('name')
@include('view.name')
@include('view.name', array('key' => 'value'));
@lang('messages.name')
@choice('messages.name', 1);
@if
@else
@elseif
@endif
@unless
@endunless
@for
@endfor
@foreach
@endforeach
@while
@endwhile
//forelse 4.2 feature
 @forelse($users as $user)
@empty
@endforelse
// Echo content
 {{ $var }}
// Echo escaped content
 {{{ $var }}}
{{-- Blade Comment --}}
// Echoing Data After Checking For Existence
 {{{ $name or 'Default' }}}
// Displaying Raw Text With Curly Braces
 @{{ This will not be processed by Blade }}
```

check out [this site](http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/) for other Laravel syntax helpers